# Storing multiple images for an item in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library

I want to store multiple images for an item (e.g. images of a building) and I need to create a image viewer control in the ASP.NET website as well.
What are good options to save and retrieve images from Sitecore? If there is an Image list kind of control that would be ideal in my scenario.

Is it a good option to use the "Attachment" field type?  If anyone has code examples, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sitecore Field Suite open source module contains an "Image Field" control that allows you to attach multiple images to a content item.  Unlike a normal multilist, the Image List allows authors to see the images they are attaching directly in the Content Editor, which can be very helpful in choosing and arranging Carousel items.

Links:

- Blog post introducting the Field Suite: http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2012/10/24/sitecore-field-suite/
- FIeld Suite on Sitecore Marketplace: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Field_Suite.aspx

Comment: There is also an older module called Sitecore Field Types which contains a nice image carousel. http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Field_Types.aspx